# leaflet map doesn't render properly in stepper from mdb

Tags: angular, leaflet, mdbootstrap, ngx-leaflet

I've integrated different leaflet-maps from ngx-leaflet successfully in my angular project.
Now I've got the following problem:
For css I'm using additionally Material Design for Bootstrap (mdb) and at one point I have to use a stepper. The stepper is a component of mdb and I need to render the leaflet map inside a step of the stepper. But the stepper doesn't load properly in css and functionality. I have added a picture of it to this question.

I think this is because the steps of the stepper change their size when going from one to another step. But I just don't know how to fix this.
I tried rendering the map & set the size again, when the related step is active,but this doesn't work. Also a common solution with the function `invalidateSize();` from the leaflet map doesn't work for me.

Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot in advance!

This is my html:

```
<mdb-stepper #stepper class="custom-stepper" (window:resize)="stepperOrientation()" [vertical]="vertical"
        [linear]="true">
...
<mdb-step #standortStep name="Standort">
    <ng-container *ngIf="standortStep.isActive">
        <div class="row m-0 mt-4">
            <mdb-card class="location-title p-2 w-100">
                Titel
            </mdb-card>
        </div>
        <div class="row m-0 px-2">
            <div class="create-map-wrapper">
                <div leaflet class="create-map" [leafletCenter]="center" [leafletFitBounds]="fitBounds"
                [leafletBaseLayers]="baseLayers" [leafletLayers]="markers" (leafletClick)="mapClicked($event)"
                *ngIf="standortStep.isActive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</mdb-step>
...
</mdb-stepper>
```

And this is my css:

```
.create-map-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  .create-map {
    height: 30vh;
  }
}
```

[image: This is what is rendered in the Browser]

Added: Some parts of the laysers a shown properly but the majority of the map is grey and I cant't interact with the map in way I should. When I zoom with the mouse it's like that:

[image]

Comment: While it looks like there is already some CSS interfering with Leaflet (given the shape of the zoom, layer control buttons, and attribution), the rest of the map does not seem weird: it would be interesting explaining what you expect which is not met.

Comment: Yes, but I also can't interact with it in the right way. The map zooms really weird and the map reacts like in the second picture I've just added to the post.